# php jquery mysql rating counter

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, rating-system

I'm working with a CMS project.
Currently I want to build a rating system there but unfortunately that rating system require's **JQUERY** I'm @ learning position on jQuery.
buy my knowledge in working with this rating system.

db ::tables ::columns   = id,path,likes,dislikes..

## Index.php

```
 <?php
include 'db.php';
include 'conf.php';

$path = $home_path;


$q = "select * from likes where path='".$path."'";
$res = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli ,$q));


echo '<a href="#datas" onclick="like('.$path.',like)">Likes('.$res["yes"].')</a>  ';
echo '<a href="#datas"    onclick="like('.$path.',dislike)">Unlikes('.$res["no"].')</a>';
```

**Here I wanted to send my parameters with like() function and pass them via jQuery and contact the php page ..and I want the results back from that php page. Like I want to get the json reply **

Kindly please help me.
I meant I need that full jquery code.
And can you please explain me how is that working.

Like what I tried to say is:

## index.php & #post_rating.php

```
 <head>
  <title>The jQuery Example</title>
  <script type ="text/javascript" 
  src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js">
 </script>
  <script type ="text/javascript" language="javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#like").click(function(path,type){ //i want to get the values 
  with this function here

         $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "post_rating.php",
        data: "path=" +path + "&type=" +type,
        success: function(){alert('success');} 
  /////i want to show the the      
  reply which is producded by php-json page post_rating.php
    });
        });
     });
  </script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <?php
  include 'db.php';
   include 'conf.php';

  $path = $home_path;

 $q = "select * from likes where path='".$path."'";
 $res = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($mysqli ,$q));


 echo '<a href="#" onclick="like('.$path.',like)">Likes('.$res["yes"].')</a>        ';
  echo '<a href="#" onclick="like('.$path.',dislike)">Unlikes('.$res["no"].')   </a>';
 ?> 
#post_rating.php
   <?php
   if(isset($_REQUEST["path"]) && isset($_REQUEST["type"])){
   $path = $_REQUEST["path"];
   $type = $_REQUEST["type"];

   if($type =="dislike"){
   $reply =  'you disliked this page '.$path.'';
   }
   elseif($type =="like"){
   $reply = echo 'you lick this page : '.$path.'';
   }
 json_encode($reply);
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: what you're looking for is ajax, look it up on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ when you return data you will want to `json_encode` it in php. Read it up a bit, try a bit, then post what you've tried. Or watch some youtube videos on ajax.

Comment: how to get the values from **like()** and i setted them up for 2 parameter fields there..
and send the values to a php page which is collected from **like()**..
and after that i want to show the result from that page by json method..

Comment: like is your own function no? I don't know what it does unless you post it